# How can i make a discord bot say something a user says without prefix

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to figure out how to make a discord bot say something a specific user says. For example, if i say something in general the bot says what i said in the text channel. I want it to be user specific but i dont know how to make this in the bot. Thanks to whoever answers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `on_message(ctx)` event. For example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    message = ctx.content.lower()
    if 'hello' in message and ctx.author.id == MY_ID:
        await ctx.channel.send('Hey there!')

    await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

**Note:** `await client.process_commands(ctx)` is very important, without it, all your commands won't work.

`MY_ID` is your your Discord ID (an integer value), so the bot will only respond if the author's ID equals your ID.

Comment: I was looking for something like a say command, but without the "say" part. For example, if i say something like "test123", the bot says "test123". or if i say "python450", the bot says "python450". Basically, what im looking for is a say command but you don't use the "say" part and it just says the message you sent.

Comment: @LokeyNogts Like this?
```@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id == MY_ID:
        await ctx.channel.send(ctx.content)

    await client.process_commands(ctx)```
This feature would be very annoying tho.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Thank you for this.